# web.config and app.config ApplicationSettings being overwritten in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config

We've got the following projects:

- Domain.UI.Web
- Domain.Business
- Domain.Services.EndPoints
- Domain.Services.Contracts
- Domain.Services.Agents

ApplicationSettings are being added to the `app.Config` in for example the `Domain.Business` project:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <Domain.Business.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="SomeKey" serializeAs="String">
            <value>someDummyValue</value>
    </Domain.Business.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

The keys are added there for the typed accessor that is generated by Visual Studio. However the value is being overwritten by the values from the `web.config` in another project. This is the `web.config` of the `Domain.Services.EndPoints` project.

```
<Domain.Business.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="SomeKey" serializeAs="String">
            <value>actual_value</value>
        </setting>
    </Domain.Business.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

*When I get `My.Settings.SomeKey` from the `Domain.Business` project the value is the `actual_value` from the EndPoints project. And this seems to be happening automagically* as I couldn't find any code in our solution that seems to be doing this and I can't get Google to answer my question:

What is this? Is this something standard in ASP.NET or WCF? In what version of the framework has this been introduced? Where can I read more about this overwriting behavior?

Comment: I guess that Domain.Bussiness is a class library? In that case it's normal behavior. A dll doesn't have a .config file so it uses the web.config (or app.config of an executable) of the application that references the library.

Comment: It is. Apparently all the values are being overwritten by the values from `Domain.Services.EndPoints`. But no project has a reference to the EndPoints which is a project with just `svc` files. I guess the general principle you outlined still applies but that this is something specific to WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Domain.Bussiness is a class library, it is normal behavior. A dll doesn't have a .config file so it uses the web.config (or app.config in case of an executable) of the application that references the library.